# In sed, why can't I use a range of hexdecimal escapes in square brackets?

Tags: shell, sed, escaping, hex

I'm trying to run:

```
sed 's/[\xE0-\xEF]/_/g;
```

but am getting a complaint about an "invalid collation character". What's wrong with my range of characters in the square brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `LC_ALL` environnement variable to the `C` locale (aka the POSIX locale):

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/[\xE0-\xEF]/_/g'
```

Comment: I have tried that on MSYS (Windows) and still get the same error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Try with `set LANG=C`

Comment: no luck... never mind. MSYS is not the most representative environment.

Comment: Indeed, I'm in a UTF-8 locale. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

The non-ASCII compliant characters generated may interfere with encodings or whatever. Note that it works fine with standard ASCII ranges: `sed 's/[\x41-\x42]/_/g'`

Here's a way with `tr`:

```
 tr "\340-\357" "_" < input > output
```

(those are octal values for the hex codes you provided).

Comment: While the other answer directly resolves the issue, the suggestion to use tr is great, that's simpler. Solid +1.